# Where do I find PingFederate's "Relying Party"? (To be set in "AppliesTo" of the SAML RST)

Tags: pingfederate

I am working to understand the SAML request process using PingFederate.

I am making the SAML RST request in order to gain access to a SharePoint Online instance. PingFederate SSO is successfully set up and users must login through ping in order to get to sharepoint online.

Now I want to make a Saml RST to PingFederate STS using the Java STS SDK 1.1.

I have a working STS endpoint: https://my.ping.endpoint/sp/sts.wst
And my SharepointOnline endpoint is: https://mydomain.sharepoint.com

I am trying to figure out what to use as `AppliesTo` in this scenario.

Definition:

> The Relying Party realm the token is to be issued for.

I've tried setting it to anything we can think of. But no luck. I was fairly sure I could use: https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0 but it didn't work. I keep getting a SOAP Fault from ping STS:

`Unable to determine partner SP connection by AppliesTo: http://my-AppliesTo-url-here`

Is this some URL I need to get from the PingFederate admin UI? How can I find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under your "**SP Connection**", "**WS-Trust STS**", "**Protocol Settings**" there is a place to enter the "PARTNER SERVICE IDENTIFIER (CORRESPONDS TO APPLIESTO IN RST)"[image]

Comment: So if I'm using sharepoint online, should i set it to `https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/_forms/default.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0` ? Thanks **so much** for your response!!

Comment: I created a new question for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48390426/when-authenticating-to-sharepoint-online-with-pingfederate-sso-what-should-par
If you do answer this, let's answer it there so I can give you credit! thanks!