# When authenticating to Sharepoint online with PingFederate SSO, what should "PARTNER SERVICE IDENTIFIER" be set to?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pingfederate

In this sof ticket, [Where do I find PingFederate's "Relying Party"? (To be set in "AppliesTo" of the SAML RST)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48358507/where-do-i-find-pingfederates-relying-party-to-be-set-in-appliesto-of-the/48390240#48390240), we learn where to set an SP's "PARTNER SERVICE IDENTIFIER" which corresponds to the "AppliesTo" element in the STS soap request for saml token.

I am using PingFederate to do SSO to my SharePoint online site: https://mysite.sharepoint.com

What should the `PARTNER SERVICE IDENTIFIER` be set to when using SharePoint online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the answer from a PingFederate PDF document that was pretty hard to find.

https://docs.pingidentity.com/bundle/ix_m_downloadDocumentation/page/PF610O365IntegrationNote.pdf

The value to use is: `urn:federation:MicrosoftOnline`